# Finding the solution to this differential: $y^{\prime}\tan(x) = a + y$; given $y(\pi/3) = a$ for $0<x<\pi/2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My approach to this problem is to manipulate the differential by dividing both sides by $\tan(x)$ at first which gives you:

$$y^\prime =\frac{a+y}{\tan(x)}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{a+y}{\tan(x)}$$

$$dy\left(\frac{1}{a+y}\right) =\tan(x)dx$$

but when I differentiate this, and attempt to solve I get a different answer then the one in the back of the book.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: your $a=\frac{\pi}{3}*y$?

Answer (score 2):

Separate the variables. We get
$$\frac{dy}{a+y}=\cot x\,dx.$$
Integrate. On the left we get $\ln(|a+y|)$. On the right, since $\cot x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$, let $u=\sin x$. The intehral is $\ln(|\sin x|)+C$.

Now either exponentiate both sides, and use the initial condition to deal with the constant. Or find the constant immediately.

**Remark:** You have $\tan x$ where you should have $\frac{1}{\tan x}$, that is, the $\cot x$ of the answer above. Perhaps that is the source of the error.

Comment: ahh right that is an error. The solution in the back of the book is y = (4a/sqrt(3))*sin(x) - a. How did they get the (4a/(Sqrt(3)) ?

Comment: For $x$ in our interval, we get $y+a=D\sin x$ for some constant $D$. Put $x=\pi/3$. We get $2a=D\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so $D=\frac{4a}{\sqrt{3}}$.